# In html5 app, register.html appears under index.html - Not hidden

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova

I have an app which must changes between 2 html pages when I push over the link/buttons tagged by `<a>`. I have two pages, register.html and index.html. In index, when you push over "Registro" button the app must go to register.html. However, the `register.html` page appears under `index.html` (scrollable). In addition "loading" word appears:
Like this:
[image: Capture]

The code of `index.html` is the next:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <script src="js/jquery.imagefit-0.2.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>KirolAPP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="indexPage">
            <div data-role="header" align="center">
            <img src="img/kirolLogo.png">   
            <br>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" align="center">
                <form id="formInicio">

                    <output style="color: #d17b12;">Nombre</output><br>
                    <input type="text" id="idNombre" style="border:1;" placeholder="Usuario"><br>
                    <output style="color: #d17b12;">Clave</output><br>
                    <input type="password" id="idClave"  style="border:1; color: orange;" placeholder="Clave">
                    <br><br>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="" id="botonAcceso" class="boton" onclick="compruebaLogin()" style="color: yellow;border: 1">Entrar</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div data-role="footer" align="center" >
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="registro.html" id="boton2Registro" class="botonPagina" data-transition="turn" onclick="transitionReg()" style="color: yellow;">Registrarse</a>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions_v1.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the code of `register.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> -->
<title>KirolAPP</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="registerPage">
        <div data-role="header" align="center">
            <img src="img/kirolLogo.png"> <br>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" align="center"  id="registerContent">
            <form id="formRegistro">
<!--                <output style="color: #d17b12;">Nombre</output> -->
                <br> <input type="text" id="idNombreReg" style="border: 1;"
                    placeholder="Nombre"><br>
<!--                <output style="color: #d17b12;">Primer apellido</output> -->
                <input type="text" id="idNombreReg" style="border: 1;"
                    placeholder="1ºApellido"><br>
<!--                <output style="color: #d17b12;">Segundo Apellido</output> -->
                <input type="text" id="idNombreReg" style="border: 1;"
                    placeholder="2ºApellido"><br>
<!--                <output style="color: #d17b12;">Clave</output><br>  -->
                <input type="password" id="idClaveReg" style="border: 1; color: orange;" 
                placeholder="Clave"><br>
                <input
                    type="password" id="idClaveRegRep" style="border: 1; color: orange;"
                    placeholder="Confirmar clave"><br>
<!--                <output style="color: #d17b12;">Email</output><br>  -->
                <input type="email" id="idEmail" style="border: 1;"
                    placeholder="Email"><br>
                <div data-role="footer" align="center">
                    <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <a  id="botonRegistro" target="_system"
                            class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" onclick="checkPass"
                            style="color: yellow;">Registrarse</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>



    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions_v1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/objects_v1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The functions that must show and hide are in `functions_v1.js`:

```
function transitionReg(){
    $("#indexPage").hide();
}
function transitionLog(){
    $("#registerPage").hide();
}
function checkPass(){
    var pass1 = $("#idClaveReg").val;
    var pass2 = $("#idClaveRegRep").val;

    if (pass1==pass2 && pass1!=""){
        alert("Las claves coinciden.");
        usuario.nombre = $("#idNombreReg").val;
        usuario.apellido1 = $("#id")
        usuario.email = $("idEmail").val;
        transitionLog();
    }else{
        alert("Las claves no coinciden.");
        $("#idClaveReg").css("background-color","#f94a4a");
        $("#idClaveRegRep").css("background-color","#f94a4a");
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit with response for loading: I had not added the plugin jquery1.4.5.css.

Comment: `align` attribute is [depreciated for many elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) in HTML5. Also, try to avoid using HTML elements for presentation, i.e. over reliance on `<br>` to create space and newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexPage id is assigned to a void div. The issue is probably that you are hiding a void div.

Try to move the id **id="indexPage"** into the

```
<div class="app">
```

tag.

Or close your tag after the **class="app"** div, not before.

**EDIT** : 
Ok it seems that you are calling the hide function without parenthesis, so it tries to access to an attribute.

Just add "()" after every function in your js file.

Comment: I corrected this (and edited the question too) with the change, but still with the same fail. Thanks!

Comment: Ok now try to call hide with "()" parenthesis to call the function from jquery ;)

Comment: neither worked :S Its so rare, because, this "loading" must not be there, and i dont know why appears..

Comment: Ok Asier, do you have a logging system plugged in Cordova ? Moreover, does something jQuery related works, or you can't make anything works ?

Comment: i think is not plugged, where can i see the logg? Im in ubuntu with eclipse ide.

Comment: Hi again Asier, and what happen if you try to replace your onclick event with this code :
`$( "#boton2Registro" ).click(function() {
    $("#indexPage").hide();
});`

Also, you still have some functions in your JS file, missing the parenthesis (val functions)

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for do not respond, im so bussy with classes. I solve the problem with the "Loading" and scrollable htmls. The problem was, i think, i am  not using jqeries in this screen/html, only i commented the scripts imports and it solved. For the other hand, i have to fix the problems you are telling to me. I will come soon.

Comment: Hi @Alex, i dont know why but the onclick does not works with any function, that is more, if i put  onclick="alert('hello')"; neither works...

Comment: To my mind, there is javascript errors that are breaking jQuery in your page, hence you can't execute the onclick events. Start with replacing your ".val" by ".val()". And I don't really know how it supposed to work in Cordova, but try to get Javascript console logs. It will almost solve the problem by itself.